# Something fundamentally wrong with copy/paste script from other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this comes across as flippant but I've spent the last 8 hours smashing my head against a wall with this. No matter what variant I try, this code constantly throws up errors of all degrees. I'm competent and I've taken SO MANY EXAMPLES and NONE OF THEM WORK. I'm beginning to think that theres something wrong with where the code is in my workbook. I've put it in Module1, where I normally keep all code.

The actual problem - copy/paste values from one workbook sheet to another after selecting the file from a popup prompt. That's it. The structure of the table is the same but it will need to be moved 5 rows up on the target sheet.

I've tried so many different types of code, which you can see as commented out when I try to iterate to something different. IT WILL NOT REFERENCE THE OPENED WORKBOOK CORRECTLY. Keeps throwing up errors like I'm trying to access some hidden darknet database instead of a file right next to it......

I've tried so many different approaches but they all end up with different errors. the above code gives me 'Runtime error 13. Type, mismatch.' on the line in the loop that tries to copy the code.

I think it all stems from excel not being able to correctly reference the opened file. even though it should.......................

```
 Sub ImportEstimatorData()
    Dim xTargetWb As Workbook 'Consolidator
    Dim xSourceWb As Workbook 'Estimator
    Set xTargetWb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim xTargetRng As Range 'Target row/column in new sheet, changes row starting
    Dim xSourceRng As Range 'Source data from Estimator, Never changes

    Dim xSourceSt As Worksheet
    Dim xTargetSt As Worksheet

    Sheets("CR Data").Activate

    Set xTargetSt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CR Data")

    Dim vFile As Variant
    'fileToOpen = Application _
    ' .GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    'If fileToOpen <> False Then
    ' MsgBox "Open " & fileToOpen
    'End If

    'Dim vFile As Variant
    'vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", 1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
    'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
    'If vFile = "" Then Exit Sub
    'Set targetworkbook
    'Set xSourceWb = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
        If Not Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*" Then
            ' Is Windows.
        vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsm", 1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
            If vFile = "" Then
            Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
        Exit Sub
        End If
            ' Is a Mac and will test if running Excel 2011 or higher.
      ' If Val(Application.Version) > 14 Then
       '         Set xSourceWb = Select_File_Or_Files_Mac

        '        End If
          '      End If

        'Workbooks.Open (vFile)

        Set xSourceWb = Workbooks.Open(vFile)

        'Workbooks(xSourceWb).Open
        'Workbooks(xSourceWb).Activate

        'Set Sheets for both Source & Target Workbooks

        'Set xSourceSt = xSourceWb.Sheets("Output data GPE")

        'Set xTargetRng = xTargetSt.Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(80, 16))


        Sheets("Output Sheet GPE").Activate 'Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Select
        Set xSourceWb = ActiveWorkbook

        'xSourceWb.Activate

        'Set xSourceRng = xSourceSt.Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(80, 16))

        'xSourceRng.Copy xTargetRng

        'Workbooks(xSourceWb).Worksheets("Output Sheet GPE").Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(84, 16)).Copy Workbooks(xTargetWb).Worksheets("CR Data").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(80, 16))

        For i = 8 To 84

        For j = 2 To 16

        Workbooks(xSourceWb).Worksheets("Output Sheet GPE").Cells(i, j) = Workbooks(xTargetWb).Worksheets("CR Data").Cells(i - 4, j)
   'Debug error here

        Next j

        Next i


        'Workbooks(xWb).Worksheets("CR Data").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(80, 16)).Copy Workbooks(xTargetWb).Worksheets("C").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(80, 16))

        'Workbooks(xTargetWb).Worksheets("CR Data").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(80, 16)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        'Workbooks(xTargetWb).Sheets("CR Data").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(80, 16)).Value = Workbooks(xSourceWb).Sheets("Output Sheet GPE").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(80, 16))

       'xSourceWb.Close
    'End If
'End With

End Sub'
```

Comment: `xSourceWb` and `xTargetWb` are `Workbook` objects already. Don't enclose them in `Workbooks`. That said, you don't need a loop for this.

Comment: I would replace every use of `.Activate` and `Activeworkbook` before anything else but it looks like you should modify your error line to read `xSourceWb.Worksheets(...` instead of `Workbooks(xSourceWb).Worksheets(...` since `xSourceWb` represents the workbook already.

Comment: An [mcve] would come in handy. On top of other things a line such as `Set xSourceRng = xSourceSt.Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(80, 16))` will error unless `xSourceSt` is active as it is not fully qualified.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you BigBen! That was exactly it! I removed the 'workbooks' encloser and it worked :-)

Copy/paste response below for future perusal:
xSourceWb and xTargetWb are Workbook objects already. Don't enclose them in Workbooks. That said, you don't need a loop for this. – BigBen 16 hours ago